# Error occurred when hovering on a wxpython tab

Tags: python-3.x, error-handling, wxpython

I created a ui in python using wxpython 3.0.3 phoenix, in this ui I used tabs to represent different work areas from the library ''wx.lib.agw.aui''as:

```
import wx.lib.agw.aui as aui
self.tab_group = aui.AuiNoteook(self, agwStyle = some_previously_defined_style)
```

everything works fine but I noticed that when hovering on a tab label (page name), the following error is generated:

......

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\wx\core.py", line 1557, in _PyEvent_Clone
clone = copy.copy(self)
File "C:\Python36\lib\copy.py", line 96, in copy
rv = reductor(4)
TypeError: can't pickle PyEvent objects
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\wx\core.py", line 1961, in Notify
self.notify()
File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\wx\core.py", line 3062, in Notify
wx.CallAfter(self.Stop)
File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\wx\core.py", line 2942, in CallAfter
wx.PostEvent(app, evt)
wx._core.wxAssertionError: C++ assertion "event" failed at ..\..\src\common\event.cpp(1246) in wxEvtHandler::QueueEvent(): NULL event can't be posted
```

......

can anyone help me to figure out this issue and prevent it from happening again? any further information needed, you are more than welcome and thanks in advance

Comment: have you bound any events to it?

Comment: In one case yes I did bind an event to capture the change of selected tab but I tried it without binding and the error persists, so the error is event binding independent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on a quick test I just ran it would appear that this is specific to Python3.6
I'm still looking into it but there is an issue open in Phoenix for this now.

For now a stopgap would be to revert to using python3.5.
This is hardly a fix but provided that you don't require bleeding edge python3.6 features it'll work until Phoenix adapts.

I'll post back when a fix gets merged into Phoenix.

Comment: It should be fixed in the current snapshot builds.